# agent lotus GetItemValue SendTo, CC and BCC

Tags: lotusscript

my lotus agent detachs the files and put them into the different folders base on the destinations of mail.
Actually, it works well but with SendTo **only**:

```
found = False
If IsArray(curdoc.GetItemValue("SendTo")) Then
    ForAll elt In curdoc.GetItemValue("SendTo")
        idxFolder = 0
        ForAll dest In destinations
            If InStr(1,CStr(elt),CStr(dest),5) <> 0 Then
                found = True
                Exit ForAll
            End If
            idxFolder = idxFolder + 1
        End ForAll
    End ForAll
    If found Then
        Exit ForAll
    End If
End If
```

My question: now i want that it works also with the destinations in CC, and BCC!

i know I can do it by repeatting 3 times the aboves codes but it isn't the ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

You just have to build an array containing all values:

```
Dim varAddresses as Variant
varAddresses = curdoc.GetItemValue("SendTo")
varAddresses = ArrayUnique( Fulltrim( ArrayAppend( varAdresses, curdoc.GetItemValue("CopyTo") ) ) )
varAddresses = ArrayUnique( Fulltrim( ArrayAppend( varAdresses, curdoc.GetItemValue("BlindCopyTo") ) ) )
Forall elt in varAddresses
  'Your code comes here
End Forall
```

Comment: I'd probably use varAddresses= Evaluate("@Unique(@Trim(SendTo:CopyTo:BlindCopyTo))",curdoc) but that's because I'm a lazy bum. Essentially it is the same idea: make one array containing all addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to answer these kinds of questions is to select a document and open the properties. Make sure the related fields are filled in.

You can do this by right clicking on the document and select "Document Properties".

Once you have that, you can see the related fields you are looking for.

In your case that would be.

- sendTo
- CopyTo
- BlindCopyTo

As for the repeating code, put it into a SUB/Function with a method (fieldName as String). Then change "SendTo" to fieldName.

Example:

```
Function checkField (fieldName as String) as Boolean
    found = False 
    If IsArray(curdoc.GetItemValue(fieldName)) Then
        ForAll elt In curdoc.GetItemValue(fieldName)
            idxFolder = 0
            ForAll dest In destinations
                If InStr(1,CStr(elt),CStr(dest),5) <> 0 Then
                    found = True
                    Exit ForAll
                End If
                idxFolder = idxFolder + 1
            End ForAll
        End ForAll
    End If

    checkField = found


End Function
```

Comment: yes, they are "SendTo", "CopyTo" and "BlindCopyTo". We couldn't do something like that: ForAll elt In [curdoc.GetItemValue("SendTo"), curdoc.GetItemValue("CopyTo"), curdoc.GetItemValue("BlindCopyTo")] by lotus script? sorry i am a newbie! Thanks.

Comment: It's the same code. Just emails will not always have the CopyTo/BlindCopyTo on them. Send an email to yourself and fill the fields with your email address.